# How to programmatically detect iPad Air 2 and iPad mini 3 models?

Tags: ipad, model, air, ios8

I would like to detect new iPad models from code.
How to programmatically detect iPad Air 2 and iPad mini 3 models?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible directly.

Yo can, however, make a good guess by using [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html), if you combine os, dpi and screenResolution and make some conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at the userAgent string. This should indicate if it's iPad Air 2 or iPad mini 3.

If it's specifically iOS products please take a look at this list

http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings

There is a property you can get which looks like this in .net

> string userAgentText = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;